# AddressSanitizer error in leetcode practice using c

Tags: c

```
char * convert(char * s, int numRows){
char rows[numRows][strlen(s)];
memset( rows, '\0', numRows*strlen(s)*sizeof(char) );
int curRow=0;
bool goingDown=false;
int len=0;
char *str=s;
for(char c=*str;c=*str;++str){
    len=0;
    while(rows[curRow][len]){len++;}
    
    rows[curRow][len]=c;
    if(curRow==numRows-1||curRow==0){goingDown=!goingDown;}
    if(goingDown){curRow++;}
    else{curRow--;}
}
char *zig=malloc(strlen(s)+1);
*zig='\0';
int i=0;
for(char *row;i<numRows;i++){
    row=*(rows+i);
    zig=strcat(zig,row); 
}
return zig;
```

}`

I am trying to implement the solution in c. Leetcode has thrown this to me:
==26==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: dynamic-stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd37cc1741.
But I have no idea what is the problem. All I could guess is that row variable has something wrong. Test case being "A" 1 .
row: 0x7ffd37cc1740 "A\vI\037\244U"

So how could I fix this code? Trying to learn more about c.

Problem solved now. I shall declare 2d char rows with strlen(s)+1. Thus the row variable would be nul terminated, which would be valid for strcat argument.Thanks!

Comment: Did you compile with debugging information enabled too? If not, do so, and include a complete error message.

Comment: Also edit your question to include a [mcve], not just one function. Something people can copy  and paste and run unchanged.

Comment: You should detail what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: `if(curRow==numRows-1||curRow==0)`: `curRow` will be 0 on the first iteration, so next you will be `!goingDown` and do `curRow--` and then you access before the array, which is invalid.

Comment: The `strcat` loop seems to call `strcat` with 2nd argument that is not a null-terminated string, as well as not nearly allocating enough space

Comment: @M.M That is the reason. When I tried to allocate more for 2d char rows, I passed the code.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem (or at least, one of) is in the first line of the function definition.

```
char rows[numRows][strlen(s)];
```

declares a 2D char array on the stack. You should not declare variables with size dependent on runtime in the stack (in this case, because of the variables s and numrows passed to the function).

You should instead allocate memory dynamically using malloc or alternatives -

```
char ** rows = malloc(sizeof(char *)*numrows); // allocate memory to store `num_rows` char pointers
// for each element in rows, create a pointer with num_columns of chars amount of space
for(int i = 0 ; i < num_columns ; i++){
    rows[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * num_columns); // store pointer in rows[i]
    // memset this memory as needed
}
// now rows[x][y] will be one char
```

Note that you will need to allocate one more char than the number of characters in your string to add the null terminator in C char arrays.
This will likely get rid of the buffer overflow error, although your program may contain other flaws.

Comment: This is completely incorrect, support for runtime-sized arrays was added 22 years ago

Comment: @M.M, you are right, you can definitely declare a runtime sized array and the compiler won't complain. However, it is still stored on the stack. Stack size is limited, and dynamic arrays should be alloc'd

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bWW3xv, a short demo showing the segfault using static memory